# Chart.js -> Displaying % on pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to display the percentage of the pie chart that each user represents. I discovered the tooltipTemplate code while looking but it doesn't seem to be working and I don't get any errors. Anybody ever tried this before? My chart loads fine, just not the percentage.

I have the following code and have linked numeral.js script (as was recommended) -

```
// this array is necessary for generating links
    var ids = [
        @foreach($user->frontline as $person)
            {
                id: {{ $person->id }},
                label: "{{ $person->full_name }}",
                value: {{ $person->business_month_volume }},
                tooltipTemplate: " <%if (segmentLabel){%><%=segmentLabel%>: <%}%><%= numeral(value).format('($0,0[.]00)') %> - <%= numeral(circumference / 6.283).format('(0[.][00]%)') %>"
            },
        @endforeach
    ];

    // pie chart
    var data = [
        @foreach($user->frontline as $person)
            {
                id: {{ $person->id }},
                value: {{ $person->business_year_volume }},
                color: "{{ $colors[$index]['primary'] }}",
                highlight: "{{ $colors[$index]['highlight'] }}",
                label: "{{ $person->full_name }}",
                labelColor: "black",
                labelFontSize: '16px',
                segmentLabel: '16px'
            },
            <?php
                if($index < count($colors) -1) $index ++;
                else $index = 0;
            ?>
        @endforeach
    ];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279205/how-to-display-sign-on-mouse-hover-in-pie-chart . Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I read about [ChartNew.JS](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js), that should contain the function you need (see the sample here: http://fvancop.github.io/ChartNew.js/). Haven't used it myself yet but I think it could help you out!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, we're sticking with Chart.js for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the data so that it adds up to 100. So if you had a pie chart for fruits and you had 6 oranges, 7 apples, 3 bananas. You would have 16 pieces of fruit total so make the segment for oranges = 6/16, apples = 7/16 and 3/16 bananas